# Rails :inverse_of Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :picture, :username
  has_many :entries, :class_name => "Entry", :inverse_of => :user

  has_many :sent_messages, :inverse_of => :sender, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :recieved_messages, :inverse_of => :target, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "target_id"

  has_many :mails, :inverse_of => :user
  ...
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :message, :seen, :title
  belongs_to :sender, class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :sent_messages
  belongs_to :target, class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :recieved_messages
end

class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :sender
      t.references :target
      t.string :title
      t.string :message
      t.boolean :seen

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have these two models. When I try to get user's sent messages (user.sent_messages) I get an error like this:

```
Could not find the inverse association for sent_messages (:sender in Message)
```

It's my second day using Rails so it may be trivial, but I don't see it.

PS: If I delete the :inverse_of => :sender from class User, the user.sent_messages works but as I understand :inverse_of is important.

**PPS: Found the error! In the Message class I was using class_name instead of :class_name.**

Comment: what a mistake i can't belive it.. i was looking at your answer for half and hour and couldn't figure it out, googling and even the answer i gave you i knew it kinda didn't have sense but i said lets give it a try. Good question and thnx for making me aware of "inverse_of" syntax

Answer (score 0):

That's why i prefer to use the new style hash wherever possible

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :message, :seen, :title
belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :sent_messages
belongs_to :target, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :recieved_messages
end
```

Though as with many things, it's often a question of personal taste :)